# Merge two dataframes based on row values of one frame and Column value of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

I have a data frame which has a first column as list of companies and rest columns are the sector names like industrial, information technology, sports , new etc.

First columns consists of the company names, rest columns is filled with zeroes and 1 according to which sector it belongs as shown below.

```
category_list   News    Research    Health  Manufacturing   
NDTV          1        0          0          0  
ESPN          0        1          0          0  
Reliance      0        0          0          1
Ambuja        0        0          0          1
ABV           1        0          0          0
```

I need to create a mapping with two columns first one with company names and the its sector name.

Expected output

```
category_list    sector
NDTV              News
ESPN              Research
Reliance          Manufacturing
Ambuja            Manufacturing
ABV               News
```

Currently I am aware only of grouping by and fetching the companies one column after another.

```
test = d1.loc[d1['Health'] == 0]
```

Comment: `df.set_index('category_list').idxmax()` if each row has just one `1` , else please provide an example output

Comment: `df.set_index('category_list').idxmax(1)` @anky :)

Comment: check out `stack`

Comment: @anky_91 this way I will only get the top most one fetched for a particular column I suppose.

Comment: @AravindS `df.set_index('category_list').idxmax(1)` matches your expected output